# Using Language Cloud human translations with Translation Manager

Tags: 2013-sp1, translation-manager, language-cloud

Language Cloud (http://www.sdl.com/languagecloud/) now has both human translation and machine translation options. There is an API for each of these. Can anyone confirm whether we can use the human translation part (also called 'Managed Translation Services') with Tridion Translation Manager?

I've read Alvin's community post about setting this up for (BeGlobal) machine translation (https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/03/03/setting-up-sdl-language-cloud-on-sdl-tridion-2013-sp1), but cannot find any information on whether this can also use the human translation part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to use Language Cloud Managed Translation at this moment. It is of course something we are looking into supporting, but we do not yet know the timeline.

Comment: Is it for human Transalation only or for Machine translation aslo? As I have generated the API key in the sandbox mode and used it in my Publication for translation with Quality level as "Machine Translation".At the time of retriving the translated item I am getting a 404 error like this ::"RetrieveFromTranslation The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found".  Am I missing any configuration or the Language cloud is down at the moment?

Comment: Is the sandbox mode ok to test my Tridion translation manager? Or do I have to create an API key in normal mode?